# Deleting photos from phone using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios

The documentation indicates : pick a photo from library or camera roll and delete with user permission.

Is that possible using `UIImagePickerController`? Or does a user have to explicitly delete the selected photo?

Comment: You do see the part of the documentation you quoted that says "delete *with user permission*"?

Comment: actually I never quoted the docs.It could be by chance.

Comment: **Your question** says "the documentation indicates", which is what I mentioned. If the documentation does not indicate that, please edit your question so it's more factual. :-) In any event, the fact that the controller name includes `UI` as it's first two characters indicates `U`ser `I`nterface, which means the user is involved.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible regardless of what you use to try to accomplish it. The UIImagePickerController is only for choosing photos and does not modify them in any way. A more promising way, would be with the [Assets Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) but, even with this framework, you are unable to delete a users photos. That being said, if you want to use this functionality in your app, it will have to be for jailbroken devices only.

In short, the user has to navigate to the photos app and delete the images themselves.

Comment: why would you suggest that jailbreaking is OK?

Comment: @ArseniyBanayev Sorry, I assumed because it happened immediately after you commented.

Comment: so why would you suggest that it's a practice one should consider for one's apps?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the iOS 8 Photos Framework, you can now delete images from the user library! I recommend you check out [Apple's example app using the Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for a more detailed example of how to use it, but the relevant bit is:

```
//under SamplePhotosApp/AAPLAssetViewController.m

// Delete asset from library
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[self.asset]];
} completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

where `self.asset` is a `PHAsset` object ([which can be acquired in several ways](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAsset/fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:)) referring to the photo you wish to delete. Oh, and don't forget to import the Photos framework!

Hope this helps!